# Is it possible to specify a particular target within a scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a static library that has full and lite variants

Then I have an app which has a target to link to the full version of the library and another target to link to the lite version of the library.

Sometimes I want to build the full app and sometimes I want to build the lite app.

A problem comes about because I am using the XCode plugin within Jenkin for automated builds and you supply to that the workspace and the targer, however the plugin is pretty shoddy and ignores the target, thus if I only have a single scheme I have no control over which target gets built.

Thus I thought about creating a lite scheme and a full scheme, however a scheme seems to contain all targets and there doesn't seem to be anyway of including/excluding which target/targets the scheme should contain. If there is where is it? I can't find it anywhere.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Build step from the scheme editor to add and remove targets to build for the scheme. To exclude a target from a build for the scheme, select the target and click the minus button below the target list.